# How to create PayPal credit card button to my Wix website

Tags: button, paypal, velo

Can you guide me on how to add the PayPal credit card button to my Wix website? I've already connected PayPal to my site, but I'm not sure how to integrate the option for customers to pay with their credit or debit cards through PayPal.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Add Elements -> Payments -> PayPal Buttons`
[image]

Comment: this is paypal button i want to added paypal cardit card button